# Can I write this sum as a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectorization

Let $\eta$ be a $n \times p$ matrix and $\Sigma$ a $p\times p$ matrix. Is it possible to rewrite the sum over element-wise quadratic forms,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \eta_i^T \ \Sigma \ \eta_i,$$

where $\eta_i$ is the i-th row of eta and thus a $p \times 1$ vector, so that we eliminate the sum and have a matrix product (vectorization)?

Comment: How about $\operatorname{Tr}\left(\eta\Sigma\eta^T\right)$ ?

Comment: @greg Thanks; I forget these tricks and need to freshn up my matrix algebra.

Comment: @greg I feel mentioning the trace version here is usually bad advice, as I have seen people actually implementing it this way then, which is incredibly wasteful as only the diagonal is needed. Imo trace should usually be avoided for this reason. Really what we want is the Frobenius inner product.

Comment: @Hyperplane I need to implement this indeed. Could you be more specific on what is needed?

Comment: I will provide an answer shortly

Comment: Presumably $\eta_i$ is the $i$th *column* of $\eta$? What are the relative sizes of $n,p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple equivalent ways to represent the quantity, here are 5 of them:

1. $y = \sum_i x_i^T A x_i = \sum_{ijk} X_{ij} X_{ik} A_{jk}$ (index notation)
2. $y = A_{jk} X_{ij} X_{ik}$ ([Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), ignoring upper/lower index distinction)
3. $y = \operatorname{tr}(X A X^T)$ (trace formulation)
4. $y = \big\langle A, X^T X\big\rangle_{\mathbf F}$ ([Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product))
5. $y = A\cdot X^{\otimes 2} = A\cdot (X\otimes X)$ (where "$\cdot$" is the appropriate [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction))

All of these are equivalent, if you need some guidance to understand the differences let me know.

In any case my recommendation if you need to implement this is to get comfortable with Einstein notation and make use the very powerful `einsum` function that many linear algebra frameworks offer nowadays. It can be very useful anytime you deal with products of tensors. In essence, what we need is a description of the axis of the input tensors and how they should be combined. Here, in Einstein notation we have $y = A_{jk} X_{ij} X_{ik}$, so then, for example in python we would have

```
y = np.einsum("ij,ik,jk->", X, X, A)
```

If instead, you were were interested in computing $x^T A x$ multiple times for different $x$'s (i.e. batch computation) then you would do $y_i = A_{jk} X_{ij} X_{ik}$, i.e.

```
y = np.einsum("ij,ik,jk->i", X, X, A)
```

Or, if you want to compute your quantity in batch mode for multiple (capital) $X$'s, then you'd collect them in a 3-rd order tensor/list of matrices $T_{mij} = X^{(m)}_{ij}$ and compute

```
y = np.einsum("mij,mik,jk->m", T, T, A)
```

which would be the list/vector of containing the scalar results. As you can see, `einsum` is very versatile. Moreover, it is really fast as it internally can perform several optimization schemes (cf. [Matrix chain multiplication problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)), as long as you can afford to have everything in memory (higher order tensors get very memory heavy very fast.)

If, for any reason, you cannot use the einsum approach, you should use the Frobenius inner product variant, which boils down to

```
y = np.sum(A * (X.T.dot(X)))
```

In any case, **never** do `np.trace(X.dot(A.dot(X.T))` as this is an order of magnitude less efficient since you end up computing all entries of $X\cdot A\cdot X^T$, but the trace ignores everything but the diagonal. The cost would be $\mathcal O(np^2 + n^2 p)$ as opposed to $\mathcal O(np^2)$ of the Frobenius version

Comment: Thanks -- I need a moment to process the infos and then will get back with questions probably. The focus is efficient implementation, for large $n$ in my notation, and small $p$ (e.g. $p=2$)

Comment: The Frobenius inner product is exactly what I needed for my application. I will look in the EInstein notation in case I need to do the more complex batch processing.

Comment: Final note: the gain in efficiency by the Frobenius inner product is indeed very very impressive, as compared to earlier implementations I made using the trace formulation and `R`'s `apply` function. Thanks again, saves much time.

Comment: Is there a reason you write `np.einsum("ij,ik,jk->", X, X, A)` in this particular order ? Is it different performance-wise from `np.einsum("ij,jk,ik,->", X, A, X)` ? Also, what would be the best choice for the `optimize` parameter ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I would assume the order is irrelevant, as long as the index trace is semantically the same. For the optimize parameter, "optimal" finds the best order by brute force, which is however only feasible for a small number of operands.

Comment: @GabrielRomon oh and I like to write the two X's together because it is closer to the Taylor formula. If you compare the $1d\to 1d$ version $f(x)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2$ with the standard $Nd\to 1d$ version $f(x)\approx f(x_0) + \operatorname{J}f(x_0)(x-x_0) +\frac{1}{2} (x-x_0)^T \operatorname{H}f(x_0)(x-x_0)$, one may ask: "where did the $x^2$ term go"? There is a more general form: $f(x)\approx f(x_0) + \operatorname{D}f(x_0) (x-x_0) +  \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{D}^2f(x_0) (x-x_0)^{\otimes 2}  +  \frac{1}{3!}\operatorname{D}^3f(x_0) (x-x_0)^{\otimes 3} + \ldots$